# activerecord-2.3.14 breaks with ruby 1.9.2 ::undefined method `reject' for "4":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-1.9.2

```
 undefined method `reject' for "4":String
```

is thrown when I try to perform @user.update_attributes(params).

The params list is as follows

```
"user"=>{"login"=>"admin", "first_name"=>"Admin", "last_name"=>"Admin", "email"=>"nfsurveytest+admin@neurofocus.com", "location_id"=>"1", "last_login_at_text"=>"Never logged in", "password"=>"", "password_confirmation"=>"", "role_ids"=>"4", "active"=>"true", "is_staff"=>"true"},
```

The error stack is as below

```
/home/narendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@nf_schedule/gems/activerecord-2.3.14   /lib/active_record/associations.rb:1336:in block in collection_accessor_methods'
/home/narendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@nf_schedule/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/base.rb:2918:inblock in assign_attributes'
/home/narendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@nf_schedule/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/base.rb:2914:in each'
/home/narendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@nf_schedule/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/base.rb:2914:inassign_attributes'
/home/narendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@nf_schedule/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/li b/active_record/base.rb:2787:in attributes='
/home/narendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@nf_schedule/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/base.rb:2671:inupdate_attributes_inside_transaction'
 /home/narendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@nf_schedule/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/narendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@nf_schedule/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:intransaction'
/home/narendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@nf_schedule/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in transaction'
/home/narendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@nf_schedule/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:inwith_transaction_returning_status'
/home/narendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@nf_schedule/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/base.rb:2667:in update_attributes'
/home/narendra/workspace/nf_schedule/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:100:inupdate'
```

I assume this breaks as String in ruby 1.9.2 does not mixin 'Enumerable'.
Can anyone confirm if this is an issue or I am missing something?

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3434

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're supplying a String where ActiveRecord is expecting an Array. You could remap the offending parameter in the controller using something like this:

```
if (params[:user])
  params[:user][:role_ids] = [ params[:user][:role_ids] ]
end
```

You could also adjust your form so that the field is named `role_ids[]` instead of just `role_ids` so that it will be submitted as an array.

Comment: The params are generated by form submit. What I wish activerecord should handle this gracefully. It would not be nice to patch code like this everywhere in the code

Comment: You shouldn't patch ActiveRecord to handle a bad form submission. You're not supposed to be sending in data structured that way, so it's surprising it worked at all in the first place.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine in with ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.14. I am facing the problem when I migrated to ruby 1.9.2. I believe that for radio button which I am using that is how rails used to handle (the selected option is sent as a String). I am not sure if there are rails helper to format the radio button input as array element instead of string( ex: role_ids"=>["4"] instead of role_ids"=>"4"). So do you think it is still a bad form submission or radio button helper should be fixed?